# React native expo browser loading forever no logs on apllication

Tags: react-native, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to learn react native.
Earlier I downloaded a sample project and had the below code for TextInput component

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput as Input } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../core/theme';

type Props = React.ComponentProps<typeof Input> & { errorText?: string };

const TextInput = ({ errorText, ...props }: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Input
      style={styles.input}
      selectionColor={theme.colors.primary}
      underlineColor="transparent"
      mode="outlined"
      {...props}
    />
    {errorText ? <Text style={styles.error}>{errorText}</Text> : null}
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 12,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface,
  },
  error: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: theme.colors.error,
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
    paddingTop: 4,
  },
});

export default memo(TextInput);
```

and used it like below in a screen

```
        label="Email"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={email.value}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!email.error}
        errorText={email.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
```

but I couldnt exactly understand it as I thought its a bit complicated so I changed the Text input component to below

```
import React, {FC, memo} from "react";
import {View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import {theme} from "../core/theme";

interface Props {
    placeHolder: string;
    onChangeText: (text: string) => void;
    secureTextEntry?: boolean
}

const TextInput :FC<Props> = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput placeHolder={props.placeHolder} onChangeText={props.onChangeText} secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry || false}></TextInput>
        </View>
    )
}

export default TextInput;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        marginVertical: 12,
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface,
    },
    error: {
        fontSize: 14,
        color: theme.colors.error,
        paddingHorizontal: 4,
        paddingTop: 4,
    },
});
```

and used it in a screen like below

```
      <TextInput
          // placeHolder="Name"
          // onChangeText={(text) => console.log(text)}/>
```

Now when I reloaded it in browser the page kept on loading for a few longer seconds and then crashed.
I saw the below error
[image]

I dont see any error logs as well on the terminal (where I did expo start). How do I debug this? or whats the issue with my code? please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Full working project [here](https://github.com/mrpmohiburrahman/infiniteLoading)

In your `custom TextInput component` you are returning a `TextInput` like the image below. But React-Native doesn't know what that TextInput is.

[image: TextInput]

React-Native knows the `<View>`, cause you've imported it at the top like the following

```
import {View, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
```

But it doesn't know what `TextInput` is. so you need to import it.

DO NOT DO IT RIGHT AWAY

Also, you have given your custom component name "TextInput" (on your 2nd code block) which is as same as one of the core component of React-Native "[TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/textinput)". So, in that case, you either have to rename your custom Component name here `const TextInput :FC<Props> = (props) => {...` to anything other than TextInput, or you need to import TextInput from react-native with an alias like the following:

```
import { View, TextInput as Input } from 'react-native';
```